# Set Cursor Focus

Tags: vb6, focus, cursor, tabindex

I have a Function.  In a part of the logic within this Function (Function1) I have a call to Function2(x)

This passes variable x into this new function (Function2) and opens a form.  (frmexample)

How can I set the cursor to load in a particular text box?  At the moment by default when the form loads, the cursor is in the first textbox on the form.

I've tried:

```
frmexample.txtputcursorinthisbox.SetFocus
```

Which doesn't work, the tab index is 31, perhaps there is a way to use this information to correct the cursors placement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this in the wrong place - before I (frmexample.show)

```
frmexample.txtputcursorinthisbox.SetFocus
```

This worked fine once it was in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set focus on an object while in form load event.
Try focus an object in form activate event.

Like below example code:

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
frmexample.txtputcursorinthisbox.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If this control needs to be the first in the tab order, set the `TabIndex` on all the controls to suit. The control with the lowest `TabIndex` value and can get focus will receive the focus when the form loads.